# How do I use a case statement to loop through an array of objects and add a value to a key inside the array?

Tags: ruby, case-statement

I would like to look through an array of objects using a case statement and add a new value to the key name. I am new to programming please use the most simple examples and explanations.

I've attempted to write a case statement as using the equals operator to add the new value to the key name.

```rb
beatles = [
    {
      name: nil,
      nickname: "The Smart One"
    },
    {
      name: nil,
      nickname: "The Funny One"
    },
    {
      name: nil,
      nickname: "The Cute One"
      },
    {
      name: nil,
      nickname: "The Quiet One"
    }
  ]

  i = 0
  while i < beatles.length
    case beatles
    when nickname == "The Smart One"
        name = "John"
    when nickname == "The Funny One"
        name = "Ringo"
    when nickname == "The Cute One"
        name = "Paul"
    when nickname == "The Quiet One"
        name = "George"
    end
    i += 1
  end

  i = 0
  while i < beatles.length
    puts "Hi, I'm #{beatles[i][:name]}.  I'm #{beatles[i][:nickname]}!"
    i += 1
  end
```

Comment: Do you really need an array containing 4 separate hashes?  It seems rather bass-ackwards to be starting with the `:nickname` and then matching it with the `:name`, when most people would consider `:name` to be the accepted unique identifier for a beatle.  Why not build a single hash `beatles` using `:name` as key and `:nickname` as value rather than doing this in stages?

Comment: Not sure this was a homework assignment.

Comment: Did the homework assignment give you the array of hashes as a starting point?

Comment: Yes that's the part I started with was the Beatles array of hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody uses `while` loop in Ruby (we use `Enumerable#each`, `Enumerable#map` and `Enumerable#reduce` instead,) but for the sake of the answering the question stated here is the requested version.

```
while i < beatles.length
  beatles[i][:name] =
    case beatles[i][:nickname]
    when "The Smart One" then "John"
    when "The Funny One" then "Ringo"
    when "The Cute One" then "Paul"
    when "The Quiet One" then "George"
    end
  i += 1
end
```

`case` compares its argument against variants (using `Object#===` method.) Also, you don’t want to assign `name` *inside* `case`, it’s better to assign it to the result of `case` instead.

---

The Ruby idiomatic version:

```
beatles.each do |beatle|
  beatle[:name] =
    case beatle[:nickname]
    when "The Smart One" then "John"
    when "The Funny One" then "Ringo"
    when "The Cute One" then "Paul"
    when "The Quiet One" then "George"
    end
end
```

Comment: Similarly, the output is a one-liner: `beatles.each { |beatle| puts "Hi, I'm #{beatle[:name]}.  I'm #{beatle[:nickname]}!" }`

Comment: @pjs I see. Thank you.